# SQL Server Launchpad service does not start

Tags: r, sql-server

I installed R (in database) on a Dev SQL Server 2016. When I try to start the SQL Server Launchpad service, it fails with the message 'Unable to start MSSQLLaunchpad on server...'

I installed the latest version of R as I read that the latest version of R fixed some issues related to service not being started.

I did the following since the event log indicated issues related to auditing (Audit Sensitive Privilege Use) and since this is a Dev server, I wasn't concerned with auditing. I went to

Policies->Windows Settings->Security Settings->Advanced Audit Policy Configuration->Audit Policies->Privilege Use->Set - Audit Sensitive Privilege Use, Audit Other Privilege Use Events, Audit Non Sensitive Privilege Use to No Auditing (Just mark "Configure the following audit events" without marking success and failure).

I added the MSSQLLaunchpad service acct to SQL Server and gave it sysadmin access.

I went to Services, MSSQLLaunchpad service - Properties.
Right-clicked the Log On tab, and then clicked to select the Allow service to interact with desktop check box and saved the changes.

After each of these changes I rebooted the server.  None of these changes fixed the problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check DB Engine and ML Services versions, they should be the same to Launchpad Service work. Thats why installing cumulative updates help (same for SQL Server 2017). [https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4014734/fix-sql-server-launchpad-service-fails-to-start-if-the-installed-versi](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4014734/fix-sql-server-launchpad-service-fails-to-start-if-the-installed-versi) Usually you added ML Services from media to already updated instance - thats why versions differ.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have TCP enabled on the server.

I've seen situations where launchpad won't start if TCP isn't enabled (and that's the default on Developer Edition of SQL Server)

Comment: it doesn't work for me.